# Getting two inputs separated by a comma

Tags: python-3.x

If user does not input a comma, how do I let user know to enter a comma before user can proceed to next step?

```
while True:
   try:
       x, y = input("Enter x and y").split(",")
       break
   except ValueError:
   print("give me good input")
```

so if user enters: nocomma
I need to print out error saying: You must enter a x and y separated by a comma

Comment: Please post your existing code

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what do you need, but the solution is this:

```
while True:
   try:
       val = input("Enter x and y")
       x, y = str(val).split(",")
       break
   except ValueError:
       print("give me good input")
```

Comment: so if user enters: nocomma I need to print out error saying: You must enter a x and y separated by a comma

Answer (score 0):

You could rewrite your input prompt to say "Enter x and y, separated by a comma" and the error message to say "Please use one comma to separate the values".

Answer (score 0):

The complete code that you want:

```
val = ""
while ( str(val).split(",") != 2 ):
   val = input("Enter x and y: ")
   try:
       x, y = str(val).split(",")
       break
   except:
       print("give me good input")
```